# Site goes down every 4 or 5 days, and a new vendor directory is added

Tags: 8

About once a week, the site goes down and gives the following error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: in Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront->processInbound() (line 43 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront.php).

When I look in my root directory, a new folder is there called "vendor" and it seems to be full of different frameworks, including Symfony. I reinstall Drupal (version 7.54) and it works for about a week, then goes down again. I tried to to disable the modules to see if that was the issue, but when I try to access the modules page, I get a 500 error. This started happening on December, and I hadn't made any changes to the site at that time.

Comment: I noticed that when I tried to tag symfony, it changes the tag to 8. Could the issue be I need to upgrade to version 8?

Comment: sounds like something or someone is doing exactly that (updating to drupal 8). this makes no sense and is not supported (there is no upgrade path, you need to install d8 and migrate the data) and definitely not something that drupal does automatically. check with your hoster

Comment: Thanks. The host was no help, but I found a switch for automatic updates. I shut that off, so hopefully all will be good now.

Comment: do you have any composer.json files in your directory tree?

Comment: Do you use the composer module?